# Limit of a sum goes to $0$

Tags: limits, summation

How can I show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n^k (1-p)^{k(n-k)} = 0?$$
I can see this is clearly true. The $(1-p)^{k(n-k)}$ clearly "beats" the $n^k$ part. But I am not sure how to analytically show it. Apparently, it should only be a couple of lines, but I can't see it. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you want to specify $0<p<1$. Are you sure the assertion is true? The $k=n-1$ alone seems to tend to infinity.

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry. Yes, I should have added that $p$ is a probability.

Comment: This might be a start.

Let $1-p=q$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n, q)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n^k q^{k(n-k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n^k q^{n^2/4-n^2/4+nk-k^2}\\
&=q^{n^2/4}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n^k q^{-(k-n/2)^2}\\
\end{array}
$